# Upload large file is too slow

Tags: python

I have video 450mb. I would like to upload it to xvideos.com  I use in my script

```
xvideos_log_data = {'login': xv_login,
                    'password': password,
                    'referer': 'http://upload.xvideos.com/account',
                    'log': 'Login to your account'}

def xvideos(f_path):
    _print('xvideos started uploading...')

    try:
        s = requests.Session()
        s.post('http://upload.xvideos.com/account', data=xvideos_log_data, headers=headers)
        rp = s.get('http://upload.xvideos.com/account/uploads/new')
        apc = re.search(r'onclick="launch_upload_basic\(\'(.*?)\'\)', rp.text).group(1)

        payload = {'APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS': apc,
                   'message': ''}
        r = s.post('http://upload.xvideos.com/account/uploads/submit?video_type=other',
                   data=payload,
                   files={'upload_file': open(f_path, 'rb')}, headers=headers)
        edt = re.search(r'<a href="(.*?)" target="_top"', r.text)
        if edt is None:
            _print(re.search(r'inlineError.*>(.*?)<', r.text).group(1))
            return
        payload = {'title': make_title(),
                   'keywords': ' '.join(make_tags()),
                   'description': choice(description),
                   'hide': 0,
                   'update_video_information': 'Update information'}
        r = s.post('http://upload.xvideos.com' + edt.group(1), data=payload, headers=headers)

        _print('xvideos finished uploading')

    except Exception as error:
        _print(error)

    finally:
        return
```

The problem is that uploading is very slow, but successful. I launch script on my server. When I try to upload in browser - it's fast.

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is very probably the Python `httplib` code beneath the requests library.

It was horrible for chunked encoding streaming in older Python versions (2.2), now it is just pretty bad. By replacing it with a custom built http layer directly on the socket and handling buffers better, i could get an application to stream with 2% CPU and like full link utilization on a fast network link. Httplib could only achieve like 1 MB/s with 50% or more CPU usage due to very inefficient buffering. httplib is fine for short requests, but not so good for huge uploads (without tweaking/hacking).

You can try a few things to make things better, depending on your network and OS setup:

1. Tune your socket buffers via `setsockoption` `SO_SNDBUF`, if you don't need many connections and have a fast network, something like 4 MB or more is possible, to reduce problems with always empty buffers on fast pipes (10GE and more)
2. Use a different http library (pycurl or Twisted with some patches for example) and use larger buffers for transfers, e.g. make every `socket.send()` call move a few MB of data and not some tiny 4kB buffers.

Python can nearly fully utilize a 10 GE link, if done right.

Comment: Actually, you could probably get things faster for your usecase, if you have a 64-Bit python and enough memory by simply loading/mmaping the whole file at once and passing it as data instead of via the files parameter. (as you might avoid the slow chunked encoding with that).

Comment: I have 1GB RAM on ubuntu 12.10 x64 server.  I'll try these ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when uploading to Amazon S3.

My browser could upload at 8MB/s but httplib or requests only at 1MB/s.

After a lot of search, I found that the httplib was indeed responsible.

The block size was fixed to 8192.

I created this Monkey Patch and tested many values for 20MB to 500MB files.

With 400000, I get the same speed than my browser : 8MB/s. :)

```
import httplib
import httplib2

def patch_httplib(bsize=400000):
    """ Update httplib block size for faster upload (Default if bsize=None) """
    if bsize is None:
        bsize = 8192
    def send(self, data, sblocks=bsize):
        """Send `data' to the server."""
        if self.sock is None:
            if self.auto_open:
                self.connect()
            else:
                raise httplib.NotConnected()
        if self.debuglevel > 0:
            print("send:", repr(data))
        if hasattr(data, 'read') and not isinstance(data, list):
            if self.debuglevel > 0: 
                print("sendIng a read()able")
            datablock = data.read(sblocks)
            while datablock:
                self.sock.sendall(datablock)
                datablock = data.read(sblocks)
        else:
            self.sock.sendall(data)
    httplib2.httplib.HTTPConnection.send = send
```