# Python requests.post very slow

Tags: python, python-requests

I am currently using requests to push a file via API to my SaaS product.

```
    file = {'file': open(file_name1, 'rb')}
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + app_key}
response = requests.post(url=push_chunk_url ,files=file, headers=headers)
```

However, the upload speed is very slow (~1mbs) despite 150mbs upload available to the browser.

This response from 6 years ago suggests that the block size of httplib may be responsible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39518613

Since that was written Python 3.7 introduced a blocksize parameter to httplib replacement http.client https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html

I can't work out though how to possible pass the blocksize parameter from requests to set this higher and hopefully solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Github Issue([Requests is slow to upload large files](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2181)) it's [not possible](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2181#issuecomment-707626600) to passed down the `blocksize` parameter down to the
`http.client.HTTPConnection`. The [workaround](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2181#issuecomment-713823366) solution is to monkey patch the `HTTPConnection.__init__.__defaults__` with your block size(here we are using `64*1024`).

```
from http.client import HTTPConnection
HTTPConnection.__init__.__defaults__ = tuple(
    x if x != 8192 else 64*1024
    for x in HTTPConnection.__init__.__defaults__
)
```